How to analyze a vector with its entries following independent distributions?
Suppose let's say we have a vector $Y$ which is distributed as $Poisson(X)$, where $X$ is an $N \times 1$ vector. Does it mean that the individual elements in $Y$ are Poisson distributed with the mean as corresponding elements of $X$? If so, how can we visualise/plot a probability distribution function for this poisson vector?

What is your definition of $Poisson (X)$?

Hi, thanks for replying, what I meant was $Y = [y1, y2 , ...]^T$ and $X = [x1, x2, ...]^T$, then each $y_i$ is poisson distributed with mean $x_i$
